# Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I did some research to resolve this error. But no luck. Please help to remove this error.

Im using SQL Server 2013

Here's my code:

```
//Declarations
SqlCommand CMD;
SqlDataReader Reader;

private void Save(string EmplID, double MRate, double HRate, double DRate)
{
     CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEmpl WHERE ACTIVE = 1", dbConn.connection);
     Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
     while (Reader.Read())
     {
          CMD = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblEmpl SET MRate = " + MRate + ", HRate = " + HRate + ", DRate = " + DRate + " WHERE EmplID = '" + EmplID + "'", dbConn.connection);
          CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

I also tried storing the query in Stored Procedure and pass value to the parameters but also giving the same errors.

Query is just basic as you see. I don't know why I'm getting that error.

Please help. Thank you very much.

Comment: Not an answer, but important: Do not use string concatenation to build SQL queries, your code is vulnerable to SQL injections!

Comment: Do you really need to select the data from database before Updating it? Why don't you directly execute Update command? If select query returns 100 rows, you will be executing Update command 100 times. Is that necessary?

Comment: There is probably a lock on the `tblEmpl` table.
_

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya My code was wrong. I mean WHERE EmplID = '" + Reader["EmplID"] + "'

Comment: Im trying to minimize the code here. My apologies. Please dont mind the EmplID parameter.

Comment: You can simplify the query by `"Update table set<<field sets>> WHERE ACTIVE= 1"` because your selection criteria is `IsActive = 1` and the you are using EmpId from the returned rows in the update query. So you can use "IsActive=1" update query too. It will update all the records in single query and you won't have to use while loop.

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya each record has different BSalary(field) inside a loop i am computing their minute,hourly, and daily rate. My code was just simplified and did not mention the computation of each employee. because it doesnt matter. the issue here is the timeout error not my code. even if I run the query once directly in sql it shows the same error.

Comment: Ok... Got it.. Are you seeing timeout error in select command or update command ?

Comment: In update command

Comment: Did answer from Coder1991 help you resolving the issue?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Nope. in my pc its working on SQL directly, but in my laptop it doesnt work. in my codes too.

Comment: I posted a new answer below. that should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the update query as below and execute it without the reader (single update statement).

```
update tblEmpl 
set your fields = your values
where active = 1 
and EmplID = parameter
```

Comment: @NikkoSunglao same error? can you show us what changes you have done?

Comment: yes, but i tried to change the value of EmplId and it worked. But the first value, same error.

Comment: You are executing a single update statement without a reader and without the select statement (as mentioned in my answer) and you are getting the same error?

Comment: Basically i can't update that particular row. but i can update the other rows. What do you think?

Comment: while trying to execute an update statement for that particular parameter you are getting a time out exception is it?

Comment: Yes i am executing the update statement like you said. I just changed the value or EmplID and it worked now. But in that particular value it gives me error. Even i update the row directly to the table.

Comment: just run a select statement for that particular parameter in the database and see how much time it takes?

Comment: Yes i am getting an error if the value of EmplID is AM0161 but if the value is AM0497 its working perfectly

Comment: Still same error on select statement with that particular parameter 'AM0161'  else ... its working

Comment: did you run a select  statement directly in the database and got the time out error? how many seconds it took?

Comment: Yes i run it directly to SQL. I got no error its just continuing processing but i know it won't display an output. because its already an error.

Comment: The parameter might have a huge number of records in the table and it is taking much time to finish executing. You can change the time out property if this is going to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fire the query directly from SQL. Then check your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **WITH (NOLOCK)** and different SqlCommand instance for update query

```
//Declarations
SqlCommand CMD;
SqlCommand CMDUPDATE;
SqlDataReader Reader;

private void Save(string EmplID, double MRate, double HRate, double DRate)
{
     CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEmpl WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ACTIVE = 1", dbConn.connection);
     Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
     while (Reader.Read())
     {
          CMDUPDATE = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblEmpl SET MRate = " + MRate + ", HRate = " + HRate + ", DRate = " + DRate + " WHERE EmplID = '" + EmplID + "'", dbConn.connection);
          CMDUPDATE.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

[WITH (NOLOCK)](http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/using-with-nolock)

Answer (score 0):

Following are the things I can suggest for the code:

```
//Declarations
SqlCommand CMD;
SqlDataReader Reader;

private void Save(string EmplID, double MRate, double HRate, double DRate)
{
     CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT a,b FROM tblEmpl WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ACTIVE = 1", dbConn.connection);
     Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
     while (Reader.Read())
     {
       //// TODO : Populate a List of model with all the records

     }
    //// Foreach records update it

    Foreach(var item in <List of models>)
    {
          CMD = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblEmpl SET MRate = " + item.MRate + ", HRate = " + item.HRate + ", DRate = " + item.DRate + " WHERE EmplID = '" + item.EmplID + "'", dbConn.connection);
          CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the approach I would suggest to follow to avoid locking of database table.

It is sample code resembling the employee table and class with having some columns in it. You need to change it as per your need.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Salary { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public bool IsActie { get; set; }
}

using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Your Db Connection String"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELEC * FROM Employee WHERE IsActive = 1", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    conn.Open();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var emp = new Employee();

            emp.Id = reader.GetInt32(0);
            emp.Name = reader.GetString(1);
            emp.Salary = reader.GetDouble(2);
            emp.DateOfBirth = reader.GetDateTime(3);
            emp.IsActie = reader.GetBoolean(4);
            employees.Add(emp);
        }
    }

    SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Employee SET Salary=@salary WHERE Id=@id", conn);
    updateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@salary", SqlDbType.Float));
    updateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int));

    foreach (var employee in employees)
    {
        double salary = CalculateSalary();
        updateCommand.Parameters["@salary"].Value = salary;
        updateCommand.Parameters["@id"].Value = employee.Id;
        updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This should help you resolve your issue.

Comment: I found that error occurs in that particular parameter only. Other parameter works perfectly. This code is too long for me. I will try to re encode that particular row that causing an error. and then i'll try again the update statement. btw thanks for your answer.

Comment: Are you facing error with the code which I shared? What exact error or exception you get with Empid value 0161?